# On heroku, is there absolutely no way to redirect an https naked domain on heroku to it's non naked domain with wwws?

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, subdomain, ssl-certificate

Have a look at this link from the Heroku docs:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords#subdomain-redirection

The yellow boxes says:

> Requests made directly to naked domains via SSL (i.e.
>   https://mydomain.com) will encounter a warning when using subdomain
>   redirection. This is expected and can be avoided by only circulating
>   and publicizing the subdomain format of your secure URL.

Is that really the only solution? Just hope that people don't type in the url without the wwws?

I've had several problems with people just removing the sub-domain from the url to get to the homepage (on https) and encountering an ssl warning?

Has anyone else figured out a way around this?

Answer (score 11):

The best idea we have found so far is to setup two Amazon EC2 micro machine instances with a small bit of nginx configuration. Then, provision two elastic IP addresses to point to those EC2 instances and point 2 A records to those IP addresses. This way, if something goes wrong on the hardware, you can always point your elastic IPs at another EC2 machine without waiting for DNS to propagate. Users going to https://example.com and http://example.com will get a 301 to the domain and no SSL warning.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl_certificate server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key server.key;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Another idea is to use the great service provided by [wwwizer](http://wwwizer.com).

Comment: Could you go into a little bit more detail on how to implement this, wwwizer seems to do the opposite. www ---> nonwww

Comment: wwwizer supports both ways. The above code is standalone to anything else. All you need is a very small computer and that nginx configuration and you have yourself a redirect.

Comment: does wwwizer's free service give a security warning while redirecting https naked domain to https non-naked (www) domain? (ssl certificate having been purchased for the www sub-domain)

Comment: Yes. Only the paid service allows HTTPS. Your certificate probably works with the naked domain perfectly fine (it's registered as a SAN).

Answer (score 9):

The best option is to use something like DNSimple's [ALIAS record type](http://blog.dnsimple.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-alias-that-works/) which provides root-domain support to a CNAME record.

You could then setup your records like so (assuming the use of the [SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) for SSL).

```
| type  | name | target                  |
| ALIAS |      | tokyo-123.herokussl.com |
| CNAME | www  | tokyo-123.herokussl.com |
```

Though there are other DNS providers that provide similar ALIAS record functionality (such as DNSMadeEasy's ANAME), it is not something in the DNS spec. This is why we have yet to provide thorough documentation on using such records. However, we aim to rectify this in the near future given the lack of clear guidance for those wanting root domain support.

Keep an eye out on [using AWS Route 53 as your Heroku app's DNS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53) as well. I believe it is, or soon will be possible, to accomplish this on R53 soon.

Comment: FWIW, I took this advice and applied the same using DNSMadeEasy's ANAME record type.  So far, so good.

Comment: You don't want both an ALIAS and a CNAME like this because that means both domains will serve the same content under different domain names. Google does _not_ like this and will lower your search rankings. Google docks points for any duplicate content.

Comment: You can set up ALIAS and a CNAME like this, then implement redirect to one of them in your heroku app.

Answer (score 2):

A 301 redirect is the proper way to do it, as the RFC1033 states that you can't point your zone  apex (root domain) to a CNAME record - it needs to be an A record.

That being said, there are DNS services out there that offer the possibility to do so anyway. I am yet to try it out myself, but [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) offers a free tier and started offering CNAME for zone apexes last year.

Comment: Heroku strongly suggests not using A record's though.

Comment: The service CloudFlare and Amazon Route 53 currently offer is known as the Alias record and technically still valid. All the magic is handled on their end. From what I understand it's just an A record with a very low TTL.

Comment: @maletor is it possible to use this configuration with Route 53, SSL, and a naked domain? Because currently this is resolving in an error when I visit https://example.com. Is there some magic configuration i'm missing?

Comment: Uri, you are probably better off posting a new question. But in order to make the DNS work correctly make sure you have an ELB setup and that your DNS for the naked domain points to the ELB. That's it.